# process.start(url) not opening a browser

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios

```
System.Diagonstics.Process.Start("www.google.com");
```

The above code does not work in xamarin-ios. Ios simulator does not open browser. 
I have been stuck in this for quite sometime. Any answer would be appreciated.

Comment: 1 sec of googling gives me `UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(new NSUrl("http://www.google.com/"));`.

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt  Yes, That works. But, I want to know why the process.start() doesn't work!

Comment: `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()` works perfectly in Windows environments, but why do you assume it to work in the Xamarin iOS framework? Read the documentation at (https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/System.Diagnostics.Process.Start/p/System.String/). "Note:
If the address of the executable file to start is a URL, the process is not started and null is returned."

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

static void Device.OpenUri(Uri uri)

or

Device.OpenUri(new Uri("http://example.com"))

Comment: thanks. I am now getting a "you Must call xamarin.forms.init() prior" invalid operation exception. Do you know how to resolve it?

Comment: did you use xamarin forms? if you use xamarin forms, that initialization not happen. thats why you got the error

Comment: Oh, yes i used Xamarin forms. Thank you!!